# How to convert the OBJ_TREND time1 and price1 into the available coordinates OBJ_BUTTON

Tags: mql4, mt4

How to convert the OBJ_TREND time1 and price1 into the available coordinates OBJ_BUTTON

OBJPROP_ XDISTANCE，OBJPROP_ YDISTANCE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use [ChartTimePriceToXY()](https://docs.mql4.com/chart_operations/charttimepricetoxy) function to convert time and price to x and y